# jquery datepicker with custom caldendar?

Tags: jquery, firefox, calendar, firefox-addon, datepicker

I hate to just come out and ask a question I've made no progress on but the simple reality is that I am not that good with javascript and only able to stumble my way through jquery.

But here's what I am attempting to do.  I am part of a play by post RPG site that recently has changed its calendar system to something that is a bit more fixed then the previous one.  I am attempting to write a firefox extension (with plans of writing extensions for other browsers later on) that uses jQuery to allow someone to click a button that is added to the wysiwyg that will bring up a datepicker that uses a custom calendar.

In other words the calendar has 10 days a week, 5 weeks a month, 12 months a year.  I've looked but for the life of me I've found nothing to even begin me in the right direction of how to develop something like this in jQuery?

Thoughts, suggestions? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show what you have done so far.

Comment: I'd love to but as said I've made no progress because for the life of me I've not found anything to even give me an idea as to how this might be done with a non-standard calendar.

Comment: have you tried jquery datepicker, if not try it, http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: I am getting the impression you've not read the question, Nikhil...using a datepicker is really really easy, if you want to use a regular calendar.  However the issue I am having is this is not a regular calendar I am hoping to use.  Each 'month' has 50 days for example.